# Package bluez-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: bluetooth

Attempting to install `bluez-utils` failed with a "Package bluez-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package" error.

```
bhanu@bhanu-HP-Laptop-15q-dy0xxx:~$ sudo apt-get install bluez-utils
[sudo] password for bhanu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bluez-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  bluez:i386 bluez

E: Package &apos;bluez-utils&apos; has no installation candidate
```

Running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` showed:

```
hanu@HP-Laptop:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
        DeviceName: WLAN Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [103c:8319]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
```

Comment: There is no such package in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Hi,Its not working. Whenever I am trying to turn Bluetooth. its  not getting on. And trying to add Bluetooth devices msg appears no adopter found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bluetooth not getting turn on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207594/bluetooth-not-getting-turn-on)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: results are below                                                                                                                             hanu@HP-Laptop:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
 DeviceName: WLAN
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [103c:8319]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that you are trying to follow the outdated documentation.
Even repology.org says that this package [is not available in any current GNU/Linux distro](https://repology.org/project/bluez-utils/versions).
It reports only [GoboLinux with compilation recipe from 2008](https://github.com/gobolinux/Recipes/blob/master/trunk/Bluez-Utils/3.36/Recipe).

So I would recommend to install actual software with commands like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install bluez-tools bluez-hcidump bluez
```

Use search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=bluez&searchon=sourcenames) next time.

Comment: bhanu@HP-Laptop:~$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
[sudo] password for bhanu: 
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.